# Javascript Regular expression for basic digits with decimal points?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to use a regular expression to validate  decimal values .  I wrote below regular expression but it does not allowing  first decimal with value like a **.5 or .6 or .1**

**Regular Exp** : `/^\d[0-9]{0,13}(\.\d{1,2})?$/`

**Rules :**

1. It should allow positive numbers.
2. It should allow max  13 numbers before decimal point
3. It should allow max two number after decimal.
4. It should allow  **.**(dot) with number like a **.5**
5. It should not allow the **.0**

**Example  -  Valid inputs**

- 0
- 0.5
- 1.55
- **.5**
- 1234567890123(13 numbers before decimal)
- 1234567890123.5
- 1234567890123.00

**Example -  invalid inputs**

- **.**(dot),
- **.0**
- 1.234
- 5.
- 12345678901234(14 numbers before decimal)
- 12345678901234.56

```js
const valid = [
  "0",
  "0.5",
  "1.55",
  ".5",
  "1234567890123",
  "1234567890123.5",
  "1234567890123.00",
];

const invalid = [
  ".",
  ".0",
  "1.234",
  "5.",
  "12345678901234",
  "12345678901234.56",
];

const rgx = /^\d[0-9]{0,13}(\.\d{1,2})?$/

console.log("Checking valid strings (should all be true):");
valid.forEach(str => console.log(rgx.test(str), str));

console.log("\nChecking invalid strings (should all be false):");
invalid.forEach(str => console.log(rgx.test(str), str));
```

Comment: Remove [0-9] from ~ \d[0-9]{0,13} ~ in your regex, then it will allow  .5 or .6 or .1 etc

Comment: Your question is actually too broad since many other edge cases are missing.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the following regex should meet all of your criteria:

```
^(\d{1,13}($|\.\d?\d$)|\.[1-9]\d?$)
```

first case: 1-13 digits followed either by nothing or by a "." followed by one or two digits

second case: a "." followed by a non zero digit and at most one other digit

```js
const valid = [
  "0",
  "0.5",
  "1.55",
  ".5",
  "1234567890123",
  "1234567890123.5",
  "1234567890123.00",
];

const invalid = [
  ".",
  ".0",
  "1.234",
  "5.",
  "12345678901234",
  "12345678901234.56",
];

const rgx = /^(\d{1,13}($|\.\d?\d$)|\.[1-9]\d?$)/

console.log("Checking valid strings (should all be true):");
valid.forEach(str => console.log(rgx.test(str), str));

console.log("\nChecking invalid strings (should all be false):");
invalid.forEach(str => console.log(rgx.test(str), str));
```

Answer (score 1):

i think this should do most of your requirment but not all of them, limit to 9 decimal places

```
( /^(\d+\.?\d{0,9}|\.\d{1,9})$/ )
```

and this one with no decimal limit

```
( /^(\d+\.?\d*|\.\d+)$/ )
```

Comment: yes, I can't think of a better solution than handling the `xxx.xx` case and `.xx` case separately

Comment: yes me too , i hope my input will help you slove the issue

Comment: I found out this case doesn't correctly match `5.` input

Comment: I think it should be `/^(\d+\.?\d{1,9}|\.\d{1,9})$/`

Answer (score 1):

The other answers don't allow for the case of .0x, which I presume is valid? I think you need to test for xxx[.xx] and .xx separately i.e.

```
^(\d{1,13}(\.\d{1,2})?|\.(0[1-9]|[1-9]\d?))$
```

Answer (score 1):

To match your values you could use a [non capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) with an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) using `|` and specify what you want to match.

[`^(?:\.[1-9][0-9]?|\d{1,13}(?:\.\d{1,2})?|.\d{2})$`](https://regex101.com/r/hWgYJ8/1)

This will also match `.01` and not `.0`

**Explanation**

- `^` Begin of the string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\.[1-9][0-9]?` Match dot not followed by a 0 and then 0-9
  - `|` Or
  - `\d{1,13}` Match 1 - 13 digits
  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `\.\d{1,2}` Match a dot and 1 or 2 digits
  - `)?` Close non capturing group and make it optional
  - `|` Or
  - `.\d{2}` Match dot followed by 2 digits
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `$` End of the string

```js
const valid = [
  "0",
  ".01",
  "0.5",
  "1.55",
  ".5",
  "1234567890123",
  "1234567890123.5",
  "1234567890123.00",
];

const invalid = [
  ".",
  ".0",
  "1.234",
  "5.",
  "12345678901234",
  "12345678901234.56",
];

const rgx = /^(?:\.[1-9][0-9]?|\d{1,13}(?:\.\d{1,2})?|.\d{2})$/;

console.log("Checking valid strings (should all be true):");
valid.forEach(str => console.log(rgx.test(str), str));

console.log("\nChecking invalid strings (should all be false):");
invalid.forEach(str => console.log(rgx.test(str), str));
```

To not match `.01` you could use:

[`^(?:\d{1,13}(?:\.\d{1,2})?|\.[1-9][0-9]?)$`](https://regex101.com/r/kD1Oc7/1)

```js
const valid = [
  "0",
  "0.5",
  "1.55",
  ".5",
  "1234567890123",
  "1234567890123.5",
  "1234567890123.00",
];

const invalid = [
  ".",
  ".0",
  ".01",
  "1.234",
  "5.",
  "12345678901234",
  "12345678901234.56",
];

const rgx = /^(?:\d{1,13}(?:\.\d{1,2})?|\.[1-9][0-9]?)$/;

console.log("Checking valid strings (should all be true):");
valid.forEach(str => console.log(rgx.test(str), str));

console.log("\nChecking invalid strings (should all be false):");
invalid.forEach(str => console.log(rgx.test(str), str));
```